# How to get the range between first day of the year and the last day of the year in format 112 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**i need to make a SQL condition to get the data for the field in the range between the first day of the year and the last day of the year in format date 112**

i try

```
{ EGACDT BETWEEN SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 112) AND SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 112))  }
```

but it does not work, note that i extract my data in XML file

Comment: If 2012+ ... take peek at datefromparts()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT      convert(varchar,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0),112) as  'First Day of Current Year'


SELECT      convert(varchar,DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)),112) as  'Last Day of Current Year'
```

**Note:-**
You can use DateAdd in sql server and After getting the date then you can convert your own Format.

**Output:-**

[image]